# How to replace a variable in a snippet in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I use javascript snippet with keybinding.

I have this code below:

```
    {
        "key": "alt+c", 
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": " const $TM_CURRENT_WORD = $1"
        }
    },
```

If I type `box` and than press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, I get...

```
box const box =
```

But I expected

```
const box =
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Or I could use another VScode command "deleteWordLeft" in command section. But I don't know how to use two command together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snippets will always insert text wherever the cursor is at the time the snippet is triggered - that is why you are seeing the behaviour you get.  If the word was first selected, an insertion would replace that word like normal.

---

The easiest way is just to select the `box` text and then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and you will get your result.  But with the extra step of selecting.

---

Here is a macro solution as well.

Using a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) put this into your settings.json:

```
 "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.insertConst",  // whatever name you want to give it
      "sequence": [
        "cursorWordLeftSelect",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
              "snippet": "const $TM_SELECTED_TEXT = $1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

and some keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+c",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.insertConst" },  // use same name here
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

---

or you could just modify your snippet so that you don't first type the variable name.  You would trigger the snippet, then type the variable name, <kbd>tab</kbd> and then its value like so:

```
{
    "key": "alt+c", 
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": " const $1 = $2"
    }
},
```

Comment: pls...Give an example.(I tried It also 'macros').But It didn't work! Maybe this extension was out of maintain (bcs,latest  vscode based on different command scoop )...or Maybe I did something wrong...

Comment: Did you use the "multi-command" extension that I linked to? That is what I used above.  My code won't work with the "macros" extension, it requires different syntax.

Comment: yes...I used 'multi-command' Yesterday.(but in keybinding 'multiCommand.insertConst'(command) is unknown.It give a warning with underline)

Comment: actually I am working on a js snippet extension for vs code.But thanks for your answer...also I request vscode team to add multi command support in github.If you interested you can check out my extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nur.just-black Have a nice day!

Comment: Yes, the multi-command macros still work for me despite the warning.  The author is aware of those - apparently some other macro extensions get the same warnings.

Comment: I updated the mulit-command keybinding.  The extension was updated last night to elimiante the warning squigglies issue.